# How to correct the use of function splinefun?

Tags: r, function

I have my code that parts work fine:

```
C <- c(0, 0.3, 1.5, 3.5, 19.5)

v1 <- c(0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.26, 0.91) 
H <- 1
n <- 1

V <- function(C, H, n) {
  1/(1 + (C/H)^n) 
}


y_spa1 <- V(C, H, n)  
x_dense1 <- seq(0, 10, by=0.1)
y_dense1 <- splinefun(y_spa1, C, )(x_dense1)
y_dense <- approx(C, y_spa1, xout=x_dense1)$y
which(y_dense1 <= 0.5)
which(y_dense1 <= 0.5)[1]
x_dense1[which(y_dense1 <= 0.5)[1]]
```

It seems to me that when I try to do the same for v1 it doesn't give me the correct result maybe because some of the values are 0?

```
y_spa1 <- V(C, H, n)  
x_dense1 <- seq(0, 10, by=0.1)
y_dense1 <- splinefun(y_spa1, v1, )(x_dense1)
y_dense <- approx(v1, y_spa1, xout=x_dense1)$y
which(y_dense1 <= 0.5)
which(y_dense1 <= 0.5)[1]
x_dense1[which(y_dense1 <= 0.5)[1]]


which(y_dense1 <= 0.5)[1]
# [1] 3
x_dense1[which(y_dense1 <= 0.5)[1]]
# [1] 0.2
```

I think the results are too low. I have no experience in this area in R, so I am asking the forum for help.

Comment: Please give me some hints regarding my problem? Am I doing something wrong in the code?

Comment: Please can someone tell me if there is a bug in my code or my assumptions? This is extremely important to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you called `splinefun` with **inadvertently swapped x and y arguments**, thus predicting x from y:  `y_dense1 <- splinefun(y_spa1, C, )(x_dense1)`.

Boiling down your code to a **[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** and plotting the results would have revealed this (and made it easier to help you). In essence:

```
xs = .1 * 1:100
ys =  1 / (1 + xs) 

plot(xs, ys)

## overlay thick blue interpolated curve from splinefun:
curve(splinefun(xs, ys)(x), lwd = 4, col = 'blue', add = TRUE)

## overlay thin red interpolated curve from approxfun:
curve(approxfun(xs, ys)(x), lwd = 1, col = 'red', add = TRUE)
```

Now both `splinefun` and `approx` (via `approxfun` to supply the function to `curve`) coincide with the data (plot not shown).

Comment: Thank you for your reply I_O. Sorry for the late reply, but I have access to a good internet connection only now. Are you saying that all I have to do is swap the order of the x and y arguments in my code, which will solve my problem?

Comment: No. I was saying that this appears to be a bug in your code - not necessarily the only one, but one easily tested and fixed. If it solves the problem, perfect, if your code still doesn't give the expected result, you at least got one bug out of your way and can deal with the rest, piece by piece.